# How can I delete a SlashCommand from specific guild? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to delete a Slash Command in specific guild but when I use the code of documentation it drop me this error:

`DiscordAPIError[10063]: Unknown application command at SequentialHandler.runRequest (D:\Bots_Discord\robbie\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (D:\Bots_Discord\robbie\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14) at async REST.request (D:\Bots_Discord\robbie\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22) at async Object.run (D:\Bots_Discord\robbie\bot\slashCommands\showCommands.js:15:5) at async Object.run (D:\Bots_Discord\robbie\bot\events\interactionCreate\interactionHandler.js:56:7) { rawError: { message: 'Unknown application command', code: 10063 }, code: 10063, status: 404, method: 'DELETE', url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/998433286261067807/guilds/998574340419366952/commands/1009128621543264396', requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined } }`

I use the command id that is in field of guild integrations
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8iSl.png

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')
const { Routes, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js')
require('dotenv').config()

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.SECRET_TOKEN);

module.exports = {
  forEveryone: false,
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('deletecommand')
    .setDescription('delete command'),
  async run(client, interaction) {

    
    await rest.delete(Routes.applicationGuildCommand(client.user.id, interaction.guild.id, '1009128621543264396'))
      .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted guild command'))
      .catch(console.error)


  }
}
```

**Node Version:** v16.16.0
**Discord.js Version:** v14.2.0

Discord documentation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUgpg.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet, but it looks like you can only delete slash commands from guilds that you have specifically registered the command in ("guild-based commands"). If you have registered the slash command globally, across all guilds, you can't delete it from just one specific guild. The part of the guide that you included a screenshot of has a section right below it on deleting a global command, here's the [code snippet from that guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/deleting-commands.html#deleting-specific-commands):

```js
// for guild-based commands
rest.delete(Routes.applicationGuildCommand(clientId, guildId, 'commandId'))
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted guild command'))
    .catch(console.error);

// for global commands
rest.delete(Routes.applicationCommand(clientId, 'commandId'))
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted application command'))
    .catch(console.error);
```